# How to count consecutive heads of a coin flip

Tags: java

I need help counting the amount of consecutive heads that show up in a row. I'm not sure how I can go about doing this. Can anyone show me the quickest and easiest way to do it for this program? I can't seem to figure it out and I've been thinking about it for a while. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class test2
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
            Random randomNumber = new Random();

            //declares and initializes the headCount and consecutiveHeads
            int headCount = 0;
            int consecutiveHeads = 0;

            //Ask user how many coin flips
            System.out.println( "How many coin flips?" );

            //stores the input in coinFlips
            Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
            int coinFlips = input.nextInt();

            //loop makes sure that program only accepts values or 1 or greater
            while (coinFlips < 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter a value greater than or equal to 1.");
                coinFlips = input.nextInt();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < coinFlips; i++)
            {
                int coinFace = randomNumber.nextInt(2);

                if (1 == coinFace)
                {
                    //Print H  for heads and increment the headCount
                    System.out.print( "H" );
                    headCount++;
                }
                else
                {
                    //print T for tails
                    System.out.print( "T" );


                }
            }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I'd say is just to count consecutive heads in the Heads-side of the if clause and set it to zero in the Tails-side. Like this:

```
 [...]
 if (1 == coinFace)
 {
     //Print H  for heads and increment the headCount
     System.out.print( "H" );
     headCount++;
     consecutiveHeads++;
 }
 else
 {
      //print T for tails
      System.out.print( "T" );
      consecutiveHeads = 0;
      // if current head count is greater than previously recorded maximum count, replace old max

 }
```

and if you want to remember the highest consecutive count you might want to add a variable for this. So the above becomes:

```
 if (1 == coinFace)
 {
     //Print H  for heads and increment the headCount
     System.out.print( "H" );
     headCount++;
     consecutiveHeads++;
     if(consecutiveHeads > longestHeadStreak)
     {
          longestHeadStreak = consecutiveHeads;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that works though. If I increment the consecutive heads in the If clause then isn't it essentially the same thing as headCount?

Comment: No, because you set consecutive heads to zero as soon as you get Tails. You don't set headCount to zero ever, just increment it. Look in the else-clause.

Comment: Would i initialize longestHeadStreak = 1 or 0?